# Are straightforward lines crossed?

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

This is contest task that should be solved by methods of linear algebra.
The problem is:

*John, Paul, George and Ringo were walking in a park - each one has an own pace, on own straightforward way. It's given that each pair of roads is crossed and George and Ringo met everyone on their ways. Have met John and Paul each other?*

As I understood from the description that each person has a determined different velocities and their movements are given by straightforward equation.

There is an option how may they walk and meet each other:

[image]

If George and Ringo firstly met each other at the point B and John and Paul at the point K, then because of different pace John kept up to meet Ringo at the point N and George at the point M and Paul met them at the point C and A (it's really possible). But the main problem is how do I prove that by means of system of linear equations?

Comment: Hint: view the problem as four lines in space (add a dimension for time) two of which meet each other and every other line and such that the projections on a plane all intersect each other. Prove that they are complanar and conclude from here. I don't know how much you consider this linear algebra, though.